# Google Trusted Store Test Drive shows the error as - Javascript is not implemented on the page

Tags: magento-1.8, googlestrustedstore

We have used **http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/google-trusted-stores.html** to integrate Google Trusted Store with Magento 1.8.  While Test Drive shows the error as

Javascript is not implemented on the page
How to Fix: Implement the JavaScript code on this page of your website.

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue when installing the same extension.

Basically the js in the extension is for the US Google Trusted Stores and I assume you are implementing it for the UK Google Certified Shops? If you are you need to open the following files:

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/googletrustedstore/badge.phtml

app/design/adminhtml/base/default/default/template/googletrustedstore/order_confirmation.phtml
```

These 2 files contain the badge javascript in question that we need to edit. In both files, locate the following code/function within the javascript:

```
(function() {
    var scheme = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://" : "http://");
    var gts = document.createElement("script");
    gts.type = "text/javascript";
    gts.async = true;
    gts.src = scheme + "www.googlecommerce.com/trustedstores/gtmp_compiled.js";
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gts, s);
  })();
```

Replace the above code with the following function:

```
(function() {
    var gts = document.createElement("script");
    gts.type = "text/javascript";
    gts.async = true;
    gts.src = "https://www.googlecommerce.com/trustedstores/api/js";
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gts, s);
  })();
```

Basically the first function that is in the extension calls a js file for the US system, but the UK system uses a different js.

Hope that gets you going.

Comment: I just encountered this with the US version; not sure if Google is discontinuing the `gtmp_compiled.js` API (it still loaded, but was producing the "JS not implemented" error on validation).  Google is using the `/api/js` path in their integration sample code, so it's probably best to use everywhere.